# how to make secure and hide .java files from being Decompile APK file.

Tags: java, android

i want to make secure my java file while making Android APK file , to safe my research work.

Because when we Decompile APK file , we can get all the source project code using some steps.

Is any way to do this ?

Comment: Use some obfuscation tools efficiently. eg. progurad opensource, retroguard -licensed.

Answer (score 2):

Its almost impossible to make your app decompilable but you can use **ProGuard** to make it difficult.
please take a look at this link:

http://developer.android.com/tools/help/proguard.html